# I'm looking for an algorithm do distribute values among placeholders with different weights

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, distribution

Ok, so this is the question.

Let's say I have a given value: 2000;

and I have the following placeholders

```
ph1 -> 15% of the total
ph2 -> 10% of the total
ph3 -> 25% of the total
ph4 -> 10% of the total
ph5 -> 30% of the total
ph6 -> 10% of the total
```

however each value may float 0,1% in any direction. And I have to distribute the delta to the remaining placeholders. The "spent" total has to be the most near to the the 2000 mark (0.1% variation maximum). Is there any algorithm I can use?

Thank you guys

Comment: This is unclear. Do you mean that `ph1=300+/-2`, `ph2=200+/-2` and so on, and they add up to 2000+/-2? And if one `ph` changes you can adjust another to keep the total steady?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do? As it reads, this question is unclear. For instance, what is the "delta" and the "spent total"?

Comment: ok, let me give you an example. 2000 is the total amount of calories you can eat in one day. the 6 ph are meals that represent a percentage of the grand total. but they can oscilate up to 2% each keeping in mind that the grand total must be 2000. so If I consume 20% on the first, the 5% has to be taken from the others, regarding their percentage. large chunks will loose more. was now clear?

Comment: the "delta" is the amount that is over or below the given percentage for the current meal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep track of the percentage of the total remaining, then it should be easy to distribute your error (the "delta") proportionally by calculating the percent of the remainder represented by each later entry.

```
PH = [.15,.10,.25,.10,.30,.10]
Sum = 2000
remainder= 1.0

#recalculation after event `i` consumes `amount`
pctConsumed = amount/Sum
delta = PH[i]- pctConsumed
remainder-= PH[i]
for (i+=1;i<PH.size;i+=1)
   PH[i]+= delta * PH[i]/remainder
remainder += delta
```